# How to do absolute positioning an element with two different target for `left` and `right` properties?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, absolute

I'm trying to get a little complicated result in CSS. See potentially impossible.

Let's imagine the following code:

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="div4"></div>
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.div1 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.div2 {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  display: flex;
  
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.div3 {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.div4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

I would like the left edge of `.div4` to touch the left edge of `.div1` and the right edge of `.div4` to touch the right edge of `.div3`.

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oOkP.png)

[If `position: relative;` is given to `.div1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldrR6.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SKx1.png)

If you have another solution to achieve the same result, I'm interested!

https://jsfiddle.net/610xL7j4/78/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong but why, you don't want to do it with 3 div elements?

```js
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      Hello world
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.div1 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div2 {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

And when you have this done, in div3 put the text hello world and give to div3 the background color whatever you want.

```js
.div3 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

I would do it bit differently with css:

```css
.div1{
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.div2 {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.div3 {
  background-color: purple;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

I think this should do the trick and with this, the borders everywhere would be exactly 1 px not stacking on each other.